# Using <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /> in SharePoint website web.config

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint 2013 site and a custom plugin. In one of the custom pages I need the requestValidationMode set to "2.0" and encoderType to a custom encoder type to get the page loaded.

Hence in the web.config (i.e. web.config for the whole SharePoint site) I have added the following:

```
<httpRuntime enable="true" maxRequestLength="2097150" requestValidationMode="2.0"   encoderType="CustomEncode.HtmlAttrEncode"/>
```

This is working, but I need to do it for the specific page or folder since I do not want the entire site to run with the requestValidationMode with 2.0

Hence I had added:

```
<location path="_layouts/15/SharePointTemplates/MyPage.aspx">
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" encoderType="CustomEncode.HtmlAttrEncode" />
</system.web>
</location>
```

But this not being reflected. I also tried adding to the sub-directory web.config, there also the behavior is same.
Is there anything that I'm missing?